# Why does datepicker disappear after clicking date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jqgrid

I'm trying to implementing add dialog with jQgrid and datepicker. But when I click on the date, text datepicker is not visible any more.  Others are are working well.

I include the following libraries and my code also follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="DatePicker/css/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" />
<script src="DatePicker/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
colNames:['No','Date','Client','Available','Shipping','Note'],
colModel:[
{name:'srNo',index:'srNo', width:90,sortable:true,editable:true,stype:'text',search:true,searchrules: { required: true }},
{name:'last_modified_date', index:'last_modified_date', width:90, editable:true, editoptions:{size:20, 
        dataInit:function(el){ 
            $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'}); 
        }, 
        defaultValue: function(){ 
            var currentTime = new Date(); 
            var month = parseInt(currentTime.getMonth() + 1); 
            month = month <= 9 ? "0"+month : month; 
            var day = currentTime.getDate(); 
            day = day <= 9 ? "0"+day : day; 
            var year = currentTime.getFullYear(); 
            return year+"-"+month + "-"+day; 
        }

    } 
},
{name:'stdStd',index:'stdStd', width:100,sortable:false,editable:true, edittype:"text", editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}},
{name:'stdRollNo',index:'stdRollNo', width:180,sortable:false,editable:true},
{name:'ship',index:'ship', width:180,sortable:false,editable:true},
{name:'view',index:'view', width:100,sortable:false,editable:true}
```

],

Why does the text datepicker disappear?

Comment: "datepicker is not visible any more" Have you check in the DOM if datepicker is still working? Not visible, is that means is hided by other element or what?

Comment: Are you asking why the datepicker disappears after you select a date? An answer to that would be "because you selected a date, that's the intended behavior."...

Comment: I recommend you to verify which data are in the input field *before* `$(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'})` are called. Is the data in `'yy-mm-dd'` format? It should be like `2012-11-15` (see [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate)).

Comment: Thank you everybody for your kindly help.I fix it.Any body have problem about date picker with jqgrid hopefully this link will helpfull http://www.mediafire.com/?yf42mg39l0c4uoe  I upload my netbeans 7.0.1 project to mediafire for people who troubling with jqgrid and datepicker with jsp and servlet.Download it and fix if you have any coding problem.All the codes are include to it.Thank you everybody helping to me(roasted,Kevin,Oleg)